# How to update a part of db object?

Tags: database, rest, patch

Let's say that we created an object User in db that have columns like name, surname and mail.

```
Id: 1
Name: John
Surname: Dee
Mail: mail@me.com
```

When I'm trying to send request like that:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "mail":"updated@mail.com"
}
```

to updated my user, columns name and surname will get null.

In my patchMethod when I'm creating object to save in db, I'm creating new object. I know that if I will fetch already existing object from db and change only this fields which are updated with the request. I'm wondering why these fields  are empty (null) in request?

Comment: Hi - it would help if you can say which database technology are you asking about.

Comment: I'm using spring JPA and hibernate, I'm not sure that important but I'm using mysql